# How to validation for sanitize_URL?

Tags: custom-field, theme-development, metabox, wp-admin, validation

Like sanitize_email validation is options available but sanitize_url options is available .if options is not available then how can i do this .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIMkX.png

Answer (score 1):

There are functions available for [url sanitization](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs). [`esc_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) is one of them.